# LOOCV formula for polynomial regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, polynomial

Is the LOOCV formula $$\text{CV} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N\bigg(\frac{y_i - \hat{y}_i}{1 - h_i}\bigg)^2 $$also valid for polynomial regression problems, or only for linear problems?

Comment: Polynomial regression *is* linear! “Linear” regression means “linear” in the parameters. (I’m also pretty sure that equation works for nonlinear regression models, though.)

Comment: @Dave Likely "$h_i$" refers to a diagonal entry in the hat matrix, in which case the formula applies only to linear regression.  But your main point stands: it works when the explanatory variables are constructed as nonlinear functions of other explanatory variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Polynomial regression *is* linear regression**! Linear means *linear in the unknown parameters*, that you use some non-linear transformation of the known regressor values (in this case a polynomial) is immaterial.

So the answer to your question is yes, the formula is valid.

Comment: The reason is that, as far as the math is concerned, your $x^2$ data are totally distinct from $x$. As the statistician, you know how you created that variable, but the math just sees numbers. For all the math knows, those observations are from separate measurements of the same subjects.

Comment: Thanks! Will the same hold for a logarithm transform of the response in linear regression? I would think that a transformed response also still is a linear regression?

Comment: That's right. The log transformation is done outdide of the regression, before it. The regression is still linear!